# Symfony 2.3.4 NotFoundHttpException status 200 instead of 404 on prod

Tags: php, symfony, http-status-code-404, symfony-2.3

According to symfony2 documentation NotFoundHttpException should be caught by the framework and ultimately trigger a 404 response, but I'm just getting fatal error (Uncaught exception) with status 200 on prod environment. On the dev environment I got 404.
I'm using this:

```
    throw $this->createNotFoundException();
```

I just want to display my customized 404 page.
I've cleared cache but it hasn't helped.
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What is the message of the thrown exception? Is there anything in prod logs?

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to check prod logs. I've found something interesting: "ERROR: Exception thrown when handling an exception (Twig_Error_Runtime: The merge filter only works with arrays or hashes in "TwigBundle:Exception:error404.html.twig".)"